# How to Send An hbs template using nodemailer its showing an error?

Tags: node.js

The templates are in `views/email` directory filename is `index.hbs` and the layout file name is `layout.hbs` in the `views/email` directory and the partails is in `views/email/patrtials` directory.

If put the layout extension as `layout.hbs` is showing ann error `layout.handlebars` not found. If set like `layout.handlebars` its not showing error. But always getting this error `{"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"open","path":"/home/user/Documents/Master Project/views/email/index.hbs"}`

To send my mail i  used `nodemailer` npm package and also installed `nodemailer-express-handlebars` for compile the hanldebars template

**This My Code**

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const hbs = require("nodemailer-express-handlebars");

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL,
    pass: process.env.PASS,
  },
});
var options = {
  viewEngine: {
    extName: ".hbs" /* or '.handlebars' */,
    viewPath: __dirname + "/views/email/",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/view/email",
    defaultLayout: "layout",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/email/partials/",
  },
  viewPath: "views/email/",
};

transporter.use(
  "compile",
  hbs({
    viewEngine: {
      extName: ".hbs",
      viewPath: "../views/email/",
      layoutsDir: "../views/email/",
      defaultLayout: "layout",
      partialsDir: "../views/email/partials/",
    },
    viewPath: "../views/email",
    extName: ".hbs",
  })
);

router.get("/mail", (req, res) => {
  let mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.FROMMAIL,
    to: "req.body.email",
    subject: "Testing",
    template: "index",
  };
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
    if (error) return res.send(error);
    res.send("Mail Send");
  });
});
```